# Making ObservableCollection from IQueryable

Tags: c#

as i try this:

```
//IRepository.GetAll<CompanyPerson> returns an IQueriable
//ToObservableList() extension method converts to ObservableCollection
 var tt =
        (from s in container.Resolve<IRepository>().GetAll<Company>()
         join t in container.Resolve<IRepository>().GetAll<Personels>().ToObservableList()
         on s.ID equals t.CompanyID into k
         from subset in k
         select new { s, t = k }).ToList();
```

I get this Exception:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'CompanyPerson'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.
```

And as I try this one:

```
     var tt =
        (from s in container.Resolve<IRepository>().GetAll<Company>()
         join t in container.Resolve<IRepository>().GetAll<Personels>()
         on s.ID equals t.CompanyID into k
         from subset in k
         select new { s, t = k }).ToList();
```

OR As I try this:

```
(from s in container.Resolve<IRepository>().GetAll<Company>()
             join t in container.Resolve<IRepository>().GetAll<Personels>()
             on s.ID equals t.CompanyID into k
             from subset in k
             select new { s, t = new ObservableCollection<CompanyPerson>(k) }).ToList();
```

Get this:

```
Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

ToObservableList() Extension:

```
public static ObservableCollection<T> ToObservableList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data)
{
    ObservableCollection<T> dataToReturn = new ObservableCollection<T>();

    foreach (T t in data)
        dataToReturn.Add(t);

    return dataToReturn;
}
```

No exceptions.

any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Debugging 101: look at the stack trace, see which methods are involved and look up their documentation.

Comment: Not really related, but why are you manually adding to the ObservableCollection instead of using the ctor that takes an enumerable?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169.aspx

Comment: @James Manning:No differences,I either get the same Exception

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you cannot use complex types to compare (t and k in your example)

try to specify condition :

```
var tt =
    (from s in container.Resolve<IRepository>().GetAll<Company>()
     join t in container.Resolve<IRepository>().GetAll<Personels>().ToObservableList()
     on s.ID equals t.CompanyID into k
     from subset in k
     select new { s, new CompanyPerson() { //here fill all properties from k variable } }).ToList();
```

Also, I'm wondering how did you implement "Company" and "CompanyPerson" classes. Can you show those classes source code?

Comment: I have one to many relation ship (a company can have many persons).thanks.

Comment: I have concern about .ToObservableList() method. Is it your own implementation?

Comment: :Each company can have individual Personel. Just added ToObservableList() implementation.thanks Andriy.